# How to remove useless space after removing google now search bar?

Tags: 4.3-jelly-bean, app-widgets, google-now, google-search

Please tell me there is a way to get rid of that blank space that was left after I removed the google now search bar from my Moto G running 4.3.

I managed to deactivate it via the apps' settings, and after a reboot the search bar was gone, but now my clock looks horrible being too low on the screen and the space where the bar was is completely useless now, it looks awful.

I really don't want to root the phone since I don't really need it, and I actually like the GUI the phone has so I don't think I'd want to change anything with a launcher as I've seen in another answers.

Comment: I don't think you can do that with Android's built-in Launcher.  Have you tried different Launchers from the Play Store?

Comment: I tried Nova Launcher and yeah I guess it achieves the goal by making the space available but I don't wanna believe I need a new application running just to move a clock up. It should be as simple as a drag and drop, like with every other icon or widget... Are there any hopes of this being fixed on kitkat?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that you are talking about Home screen.
If yes ,
**Press and hold on Clock Widget and drag it up**.

I will answer more precisely if you post a screenshot.

Comment: Yeah it is the homescreen but the clock widget wont move up, it's like if the search bar was still there, in terms of spacing but you just can't see it anymore, which is what I wanted.

Comment: Basically you can't. It's the 'persistent' search you removed, not the search widget. You could get another launcher and increase the grid size or the icon size to larger so more space is filled. Google want that bar there and it is built in to the Google Experience Launcher and the 'stock' launcher in KitKat. It's not going anywhere soon. I'd say play with Nova Launcher settings and you might have some luck.

Answer (score 0):

The Google search bar is built into the launcher. You can disable the bar, but you can't remove the empty space. The best bet would be to use another launcher (like you mentioned) or to install a custom ROM.

I have a Moto G as well, and although I love the stock android look, I am now using Nova Launcher due to it's customizability and the ability to remove the search bar.

Answer (score 0):

The blank space disappears when you restart the phone.